# Report completion of recursive function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, electron

I'm building a web crawler in node.js and Electron.

Essentially, the program takes in a starting URL, and crawls through to a certain depth, reporting back where it found certain keywords.

This is working aso far, but I can't figure out how to actually tell when it's done. Given a depth of 3-4, this program seems to run forever. with a lower depth, the only way to really tell if it's still crawling is to look at the amount of CPU/memory it's using.

Here is the function that does the crawling:

```
function crawl(startingSite, depth) {
if (depth < maxDepth) {
    getLinks(startingSite, function (sites) { //pulls all the links from a specific page and returns them as an array of strings
        for (var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) { //for each string we got from the page
            findTarget(sites[i], depth); //find any of the keywords we want on the page, print out if so
            crawl(sites[i], depth + 1); //crawl all the pages on that page, and increase the depth
        }
    });
}
}
```

My problem is, I can't figure out how to get this function to report back when it's done.

I tried something like this:

```
function crawl(startingSite, depth, callback) {
if (depth < maxDepth) {
    getLinks(startingSite, function (sites) { //pulls all the links from a specific page and returns them as an array of strings
        for (var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) { //for each string we got from the page
            findTarget(sites[i], depth); //find any of the keywords we want on the page, print out if so
            crawl(sites[i], depth + 1); //crawl all the pages on that page, and increase the depth
        }
    });
}
else
{
    callback();
}
}
```

but obviously, the callback() gets called immediately, because the crawler hits the depth quickly and exits the if statement.

All I need is for this function to print out (to the console.log for example) as soon as all the recursive instances of it are done crawling and have reached the maximum depth.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use promises:

```
 const links = (start) =>
   new Promise(res => getLinks(start, res));

 async function crawl(startingSite, depth) {
    if (depth >= maxDepth) 
      return;

   const sites = await links(startingSite);
   for (const site of sites) { 
     await findTarget(site, depth);
     await crawl(site, depth + 1);
   }    
 }
```

Then just do:

```
  crawl(something, 0).then(() => console.log("done"));
```